# Sorting requests from various clients based on timestamp

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a server which takes in requests from various clients based on their **artificial** timestamps. The time stamp of each client is generated using the function:

```
public synchronized static long timestamp()
{
    ts = ts+1;
    return ts;
}
```

This function is present in each client locally, and is called when it sends a message to the server. The server has a request queue, which is basically a **ArrayBlockingQueue**. It holds the requests it receives from each of the clients.

The client sends its **ID** and the updated **time stamp (ts)**. Is there any way I can order the request in the queue at the server side, based on the time stamp sent by the clients?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Will a `PriorityBlockingQueue` work? You can define a comparator for the timestamp to provide an order.  If each server generates its own sequence numbers you will have duplicates and no sense of "time-based" ordering between requests from different servers.  Depending on the load, requests from the last client to start could always be queued up behind requests from earlier-starting servers and never get read.  The question is quite unclear.

Comment: On a slightly separate topic, consider change your current timestamp logic to use an AtomicLong rather than synchronizing and incrementing a primitive long. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using a Queue. A Queue is a FIFO structure and is not ment to be sorted. You should either stick to the Queue and hope that the requests are stored in the right order oder use a different data structure.

How about using `List<Object> objList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());`? This structure can be sorted easily!

Comment: A Queue does not have to be FIFO structure. While that may be the most common use, it is certainly not the only. As @Jim Garrison noted above, this seems a case for a PriorityQueue. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html